# Garbage output after parsing UDP packet

Tags: java, sockets, parsing, udp, datagram

I am trying to extract information from a UDP packet but keep getting random output. Sometimes I get exactly what I want, and other times I don't.

Here is my code:

```
private static void receivePacket()
{
    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        System.out.println("\n  Listening...");

        while(true)
        {
            // Create a packet
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);

            // Receive packet
            socket.receive(packet);
            byte[] data = packet.getData();

            // Parse the packet
            parse(data, packet.getLength());

            socket.send(packet);
         }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

// Parse packets
private static void parse(byte [] data, int dataLength)
{
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>()
    String domain = "";

    // Get ID
    int id = ((data[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (data[1] & 0xff);
    System.out.println("\n  ID:\t\t" + id);

    // Get domain name and number of bits for each word in domain
    for(int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        // If the next bit is a letter then we know the current bit is the number of bits
        if((data[i] <= ' ') || (data[i] > '~'))
        {
            try {
                if((String.format("%c", data[i+1]).matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")))
                {
                    int dSize = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%d", data[i]));
                    name.add(Integer.toString(dSize));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If current bit is letter add to ArrayList
            try {
                if((String.format("%c", data[i]).matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")))
                {
                    name.add(String.format("%c", data[i]));
                    domain += String.format("%c", data[i]);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("  Domain:\t" + domain);
    System.out.print("  Name:\t\t");
    name.add("0");

    for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
        System.out.print("\'" + name.get(i) + "\' ");

    System.out.println();
 }
```

I use the `dig` command `dig @localhost -p 1299 test.mydomain.abc` to send a UDP packet to the server. Here is my output after running it six times. The output each time should be the following (ID will vary):

```
ID:           64666
Domain:       testmydomainabc
Name:         '4' 't' 'e' 's' 't' '8' 'm' 'y' 'd' 'o' 'm' 'a' 'i' 'n' '3' 'a' 'b' 'c' '0'
```

However, it is not as you see here starting from run #4:
[image]

It is completely random and I don't understand why. I am coding this on Java and Windows 10. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

**Raw Data:**

Successful trial: `'4' 't' 'e' 's' 't' '8' 'm' 'y' 'd' 'o' 'm' 'a' 'i' 'n' '3' 'a' 'b' 'c' '0'`

`b7 01 20 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 t  e  s  t  08 m  y  d  o  m  a  i  n  03 a  b  c  00 00 01 00 01 00 00 )  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Unsuccessful: `'-127' 'f' '4' 't' 'e' 's' 't' '8' 'm' 'y' 'd' 'o' 'm' 'a' 'i' 'n' '3' 'a' 'b' 'c' '0'`

`81 f  01 20 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 t  e  s  t  08 m  y  d  o  m  a  i  n  03 a  b  c  00 00 01 00 01 00 00 )  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Comment: It may be useful to simply print out the raw data stored in `packet.getData()` to see whether the problem takes place during networking or in your parsing algorithm. (and of course that would be useful to add to the question body as well)

Comment: Not sure if that's what you were looking for, but I added all the bits I receive.

Comment: On the right track. I'm asking for the raw data for a trial that produced the expected output and the raw data for a trial that produced bad output. Then we can compare the two (and improve your parsing algorithm to handle the problems we find).

Comment: Of course, what I propose isn't actually addressing the problem, but it is a good workaround. I suspect something unexpected is happening with the `dig` command (which I don't know anything about), but handling it on the receiving end may work around the problem.

Comment: I added successful and unsuccessful trials with the raw data for each. `dig` is just a command line tool for querying DNS servers. Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: I think I see the problem. Since there is a letter at the beginning of the bad output. It takes those 2 bits and saves them. Maybe if I don't the start the loop at bit 0, it'll work (bit 12). However, will it always be bit 12?

Comment: Perfect. Taking a look at what you posted, it looks like they are exactly the same with one exception: the unsuccessful packet has two bytes at the start (81 and f) while the successful packet has one (b7). Do you handle this sort of behavior in your parsing algorithm?

Comment: Yes, the regex checks for letters anywhere in there. If it find it then it saves it into the ArrayList. Starting the loop at index 12 fixes everything, but will the number I want always start at byte 12?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not familiar with `dig`. You should read up on the intricate details on what it actually does. My best guess is that if you start after the "01 20 00 01" sequence that appears in both trials you should be fine.

Comment: I will read up on it. Thank you very much for the help! Learned more about debugging from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in `parse` starts from `0`, should probably start from `2`. Otherwise the *ID* bytes will be included in the *Domain* parsing (or throw an exception that are silenty ignored)

Comment: Thanks, snickers10m actually helped me figure this out above. I'll start from `2` instead of the `12` I used.